# Measure of hedge efficacy or other means to compare hedging strategies?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio-management, hedging, asset-allocation, tactical-asset-allocation

Is there a measure of hedge efficacy or another means to compare hedging strategies?  I have seen Institutional Investors take very different approaches to tail hedging.

On one extreme, I have seen tail hedging programs that take a direct approach to hedging tail risk.  These programs will entail buying puts on the underlying that comprises the majority of the risk in the portfolio.  Obviously this has direct and knowable costs when the hedges are not needed.

At the other extreme, there are investment programs that utilize a hedging program that is basically a correlation hedge.  The essence of these programs are that they are making an allocation to strategies with low correlation to the major risk in the portfolio.  While there is no direct cost for these hedges when the are not needed, the costs would come in the form of reduced performance due to an asset allocation that may not be performing when the rest of the portfolio is working.  Also, since the hedge is relying on low correlation to provide protection, does this approach work in major crashes when correlations go to 1?

Is there a measure of hedge efficacy that takes protection and all the costs into account when evaluation hedging approaches?  How have investment managers evaluated/compared alternatives in the absence of such measures?  It seems like one approach is a direct reduction of undesired risk, while the other relies on the luck that correlation is working at the moment one needs the protection.